# Trouble with icons

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have implemented a NavigationDrawer using the MaterialDrawer by Mike Penz.
It works fine, but when I try to replace the icons "FontAwesome" on "GoogleMaterial" or other get an error "Unfortunately, App has stopped."
All working only with icons "FontAwesome"
How can this problem be solved?
Thank you in advance!

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.mikepenz.google_material_typeface_library.GoogleMaterial;
import com.mikepenz.iconics.typeface.FontAwesome;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.DividerDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private Drawer.Result drawerResult = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Handle Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(100);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerResult = new Drawer()
                .withActivity(this)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
                .withHeader(R.layout.drawer_header)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_database).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_database),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_map).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_map_marker),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_guides).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_book),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_crafting).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_build),
                        //new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_tools).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_build),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_links).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_link),
                        new DividerDrawerItem(),
                        //new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings).withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_settings),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_feedback).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_envelope)
                        //new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_changes).withIcon(Typeicons.Icon.typ_clipboard)
                )
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerResult.isDrawerOpen()) {
            drawerResult.closeDrawer();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/blackToolbar"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/tool_bar_top_padding"
            android:transitionName="actionBar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.enotboris.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile('com.mikepenz.materialdrawer:library:0.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.3.original@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:devicon-typeface:2.0.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:octicons-typeface:3.2.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:meteocons-typeface:1.1.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:community-material-typeface:1.7.22.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:weather-icons-typeface:2.0.10.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:typeicons-typeface:2.0.7.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:entypo-typeface:1.0.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:devicon-typeface:2.0.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:foundation-icons-typeface:3.0.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:ionicons-typeface:2.0.1.2@aar'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.enotboris.dayz">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

LogCat:

```
01-25 15:29:09.739 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
01-25 15:29:09.739 2594-2594/? E/Trace: error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Application.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener, referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 231: Landroid/app/Application;.registerOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.app.Application.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener, referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 234: Landroid/app/Application;.unregisterOnProvideAssistDataListener (Landroid/app/Application$OnProvideAssistDataListener;)V
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is org.enotboris.dayz, real application class is null.
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? W/InstantRun: No instant run dex files added to classpath

                                             [ 01-25 15:29:09.749  1418: 1526 D/         ]
                                             HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8b397b0, tid 1526
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.monkeyPatchExistingResources
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1926 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x025e
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.ArrayMap', referenced from method com.android.tools.fd.runtime.MonkeyPatcher.pruneResourceCache
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve const-class 1926 (Landroid/util/ArrayMap;) in Lcom/android/tools/fd/runtime/MonkeyPatcher;
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x0060
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16445: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onProvideKeyboardShortcuts (Ljava/util/List;Landroid/view/Menu;I)V
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16447: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 16451: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 673: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 695: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
01-25 15:29:09.749 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
01-25 15:29:09.759 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.getLayoutDirection, referenced from method android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.needMirroring
01-25 15:29:09.759 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1746: Landroid/support/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawableCompat;.getLayoutDirection ()I
01-25 15:29:09.759 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000f
01-25 15:29:09.759 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
01-25 15:29:09.759 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 16344: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
01-25 15:29:09.759 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
01-25 15:29:09.759 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList
01-25 15:29:09.759 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 417: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
01-25 15:29:09.759 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
01-25 15:29:09.769 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
01-25 15:29:09.769 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 636: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-25 15:29:09.769 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-25 15:29:09.769 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
01-25 15:29:09.769 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 638: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
01-25 15:29:09.769 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
01-25 15:29:09.779 2594-2598/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 261K, 4% free 10877K/11271K, paused 0ms+12ms, total 15ms
01-25 15:29:09.779 2594-2594/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
01-25 15:29:09.779 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 153 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;
01-25 15:29:09.779 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x20 at 0x000c
01-25 15:29:09.779 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams.setMarginEnd, referenced from method com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer.processDrawerLayoutParams
01-25 15:29:09.779 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10374: Landroid/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout$LayoutParams;.setMarginEnd (I)V
01-25 15:29:09.779 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0021
01-25 15:29:09.789 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams.setMarginEnd, referenced from method com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer.processDrawerLayoutParams
01-25 15:29:09.789 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 10374: Landroid/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout$LayoutParams;.setMarginEnd (I)V
01-25 15:29:09.789 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0042
01-25 15:29:09.789 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 25K, 4% free 10907K/11271K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
01-25 15:29:09.789 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 11.286MB for 589836-byte allocation
01-25 15:29:09.799 2594-2598/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 4% free 11480K/11911K, paused 11ms+0ms, total 12ms
01-25 15:29:09.809 2594-2594/? D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 11480K/11911K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
01-25 15:29:09.809 2594-2594/? I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 13.534MB for 2359308-byte allocation
01-25 15:29:09.819 2594-2598/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 13784K/14279K, paused 11ms+0ms, total 12ms
01-25 15:29:09.869 2594-2594/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
01-25 15:29:09.869 2594-2594/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
01-25 15:29:09.869 2594-2594/? D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so

                                         [ 01-25 15:29:09.869  2594: 2594 D/         ]
                                         HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb893e0e8, tid 2594
01-25 15:29:09.879 2594-2594/? W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed
01-25 15:29:09.889 2594-2594/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
01-25 15:29:09.889 2594-2594/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-25 15:29:09.889 2594-2594/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6623228)
01-25 15:29:09.899 2594-2594/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: The font for the given icon isn't registered!
                                                     at com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable.icon(IconicsDrawable.java:121)
                                                     at com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable.<init>(IconicsDrawable.java:89)
                                                     at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem.convertView(PrimaryDrawerItem.java:190)
                                                     at com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.adapter.DrawerAdapter.getView(DrawerAdapter.java:125)
                                                     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1330)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1612)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2106)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1217)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1868)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1689)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Sample:

[With "FontAwesome" icons](http://s41.radikal.ru/i093/1701/49/0dcf7789d128.png)

[With "GoogleMaterialDesign" and other icons](http://i056.radikal.ru/1701/38/8ce8313497b4.png)

Comment: ... And why don't you keep using FontAwesome?

Comment: @Rotwang i need icons from other fonts

Comment: I don't know what `build` should look like, but `settings` and `clipboard` are in FontAwesome as well. And you can choose among different ones for these. I'm sure you will find some for this `build` as well.

Comment: @Rotwang I need to use "GoogleMaterialDesign" icons and other:(

Comment: ... why? For glyphs you could easily replace with the ones already included in FontAwesome? I don't see the point in adding several fonts to your app. After all, you are using vector fonts for reducing the size of your app. So, I'd stick with a single, lightweight and very complete font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
Iconics.init(getApplicationContext());
Iconics.registerFont(new GoogleMaterial());
```

Thank you for your time!